# Why using "&" when using QSqlDatabase make error (Qt 5.2)?

Tags: qt, sqlite, database-connection, qt5.2

I always use below code to connect to a sqlite database. For some reasons, I have decided to rewrite it in a way that use `*QSqlDatabase` instead of `QSqlDatabase`.

What I did was just to use `&` in front of my old code ( **Line_12**  ).
But the code crashes in **line 6**.

Anyway, someone gave me **line_14** and It works.

So... I can't understand What was wrong with my first code and Why suggested code make 
it work.

```
Foo::Foo(QString path_="db_path_name") {
    InitialDataBase(path_);
    bool isOpened = db->open();
    if(!isOpened)   exit(1);
    else            
        queryExecutor = new QSqlQuery(*db);  // --> Line_6
}

void Foo::InitialDataBase(QString path_) {

    // Line_12 => DOESN'T WORK
    db = &(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE"));   
    // Line_14 => WORK
    db  = new QSqlDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE"));

    db->setHostName("localhost");
    db->setDatabaseName(path_);
    db->setUserName("admin");
    db->setPassword("admin");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 12, you're taking the address of the QSqlDatabase object returned by `addDatabase()`. That object is temporary and destroyed right away after the end of the statement (after line 12). So you end up with a dangling pointer, i.e. a pointer to an already deleted object.
Dereferencing a dangling pointer is undefined behavior. In practice, it usually crashes.

In line 14, a new QSqlDatabase object is created on the heap, creating a copy of the temporary QSqlDatabase object returned from addDatabase(). The copy constructor QSqlDatabase(const QSqlDatabase&) is called here. The temporary object is destroyed, but the copy on the heap remains. Note that you have to delete `db` later, otherwise you end up with a memory and resource leak (open DB connection).

Why do you use a pointer here at all? Especially as a beginner, all it will result in is crashes and leaks, as this example demonstrates ;)